# Position fixed to the body come back to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to fix the body but there is a automatically scroll to the top of the document and I can't return where I was.

Do you know how I can scroll in a fixed body ?

This is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/UBDtXTLX1Mdl35TU6XyW?p=preview

with the code jQuery :

```
var topBody = $(window).scrollTop();
$("body").css("position","fixed");
$('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: topBody }, 0 );
```

Comment: you want to this http://plnkr.co/edit/FdInHw2YOH4xUZcYtGZ9?p=preview

Comment: Nope, just come back to the place I was.

Comment: @OzgurErsil posted the solution but deleted it.  It works if you remove the rest of your code:  `function fixedthebody() {$("body").css("overflow","hidden");}`  http://plnkr.co/edit/GtFzdvRFyczIWOZnad4W?p=preview

Comment: Yes but I want to have the position of the body fixed because on the iphone / ipad device overflow:hidden is not siffisant to stop the scroll :/ Juste position fixed works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I8GCNmr4YzOeblqOgmOl?p=preview)?

#### jQuery code:

```
$(function() {

  function fixedthebody() {
    var position = window.pageYOffset;
    $(".sample").css({
      "position": "fixed",
      "height": "100%",
      "overflow-x": "hidden"
    }).animate({
      scrollTop: position
    }, 0);
  }

  button.onclick = fixedthebody;

});
```

Comment: Nope sorry, like I said, i want the position fixed because on the iphone / ipad device there is another scroll and the `overflow:hidden` doesn't work there is position fixed which works. But I don't want to change the body size or other :/

Comment: Sorry I read bad. You're right I want a stuff like this but it doesn't work :/

Comment: I don't understand how it doesn't work. Can you explain more clearly on exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: this is the plunker with your solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/I8GCNmr4YzOeblqOgmOl?p=preview but I want the overflow hidden because of the scroll on the tablets .
this is the video with overflow hidden : https://youtu.be/uh0cEoLPHIM and just position fixed arranged this. If I add scroll it's doesn't work

Comment: @MartelBenjamin Please take a look at my modified answer and plunker.

Comment: Thanks I will see that.

Comment: Like the other, when I click on the button the scroll go to the top :/

Comment: @MartelBenjamin What was wrong with the other one then?

Comment: I don't know ^^ Just when I click on the button, this brings me to the top of the document.

Comment: Right, I have one plunker that brings you to the top of the page and one that keeps you at the current page position when you click the button. What else does it need to do?

Comment: The current page is perfect but I don't find it in your anwser ^^ Is that the div with position fixed and overflow hidden ?

Comment: @MartelBenjamin Yes, my current answer (I had made edits to it) that's displayed above has position fixed, overflow hidden, and uses the current page position.

Answer (score 0):

Make everything inside a div with overflow as scroll inside the body. That will make a srollbar inside the fixed body.

ie

```
<body>
<div style="overflow:scroll">
  <!-- ALL THE CODE HERE-->
</div>
<body>
```

Comment: change ur css to  ' #toscroll{
  height:600px;
  overflow:scroll;
} '  and ofcourse you can change the height.

Comment: change too but I'm again on the top of the body :/

Comment: Im sorry ..but i dont relly understang how you want it to be done.

Comment: Thanks you to try to help me ^^ In fact in iphone/ipad device the overflow hidden doesn't work like in my video : https://youtu.be/uh0cEoLPHIM but if I put the body to position fixed it's work and I don't have the fail. But the position fixed do a scroll top automatically and I don't want it ^^